# CHROME EXTENSIONS: Message passing - chrome.runtime.sendMessage or onMessage not working

Tags: reactjs, typescript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am working on google extensions. I am trying to process message passing between my popup.tsx and background.ts

Before sending message from my background.ts, I print the data. Data exist. However, in my popup.tsx chrome.runtime.onMessage not triggered. I dont understand which function not working and what is the problem. I examine lots of example but result still the same. What is the problem? I am adding my message passing codes..

Here is my background.ts runtime.sendMessage func. this function is inside another function that is called 'collectData'. When I open new tab or update the tab, this function triggered and works. Everytime this data works stable. I can see the data in every page.

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
    msg: 'url_data',
    data: data,
  })
```

Then, I am trying to receive the data in my popup.tsx with runtime.onMessage. When I reset the extension, it works sometimes just once, then that onMessage func not working at all :

```
const [requestData, setRequestData] = useState<string>()

 chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
    console.log(' popup runtime on message req', request)
    if (request.msg === 'url_data') {
      checkWebsite(request.data).then((res) => {
        console.log('popup data alındı')
        console.log('popu res', res)
        setRequestData(res)

        // chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
        //   msg: 'res_length',
        //   data: res.matches.length,
        // })
        // console.log('popup data res length gönderildi')

        // res.matches.length === 0 ? setIsSecure(true) : setIsSecure(false) 
        setHost(request.data.hostname)
      })
      sendResponse({ message: 'res length sended' })
      console.log('res length response send')
    }
  })
```

Everytime, I change request data state. If it changes, I want to update popup with useEffect.

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log('useeffect', requestData)
  }, [requestData])
```

As a result, for the first the main problem is message passing. Why it is not working?

Comment: The popup runs only when shown.

Comment: @wOxxOm however, I also tried with executeScript. Is this (The popup runs only when shown) the main reason of the problem? Also, How can I solve the problem I need the background data everytime that new tab opened?

Comment: When the popup is not shown, it doesn't run and can't receive messages.

Comment: @wOxxOm however in every page I open popup. Is it the same meaning shown and open popup ?

Comment: The `popup` usually means the `browser_action` or `page_action` or `action` popup that is shown when the user clicks the extension's icon. If you do it differently then show us how.

Comment: @wOxxOm I understand that but when I click the extension icon on the upper right in every tab I am expecting popup works again. However, onMessage.addListener still not working.

Comment: Your code evidently sends the message when the popup isn't shown so it doesn't matter if you open the popup after the message was sent.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks for your effort. I want to ask a little question. I have a function. This function inside my ```chrome.tabs.onActivated``` and ```chrome.tabs.onUpdated``` . Everytime when I change the tab or reload the tab this function works. However, I realize that in extension page or new tab page firstly not works. I must reload the page for working of the function. What can I do that ? I couldnt find any other chrome api for that?    I really appreciate for you

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what behavior/workflow you want to achieve. Maybe you can show your entire code and describe the goal in more detail?

Comment: @wOxxOm   ```chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener((activeInfo) => {
  checkingProcess(activeInfo.tabId)
})

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, changeInfo, tab) => {
  checkingProcess(tab.id)
})```    

In here my checkingProcess function not works when I open the new tab or extension tab. However, all other tabs or webpages it works

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't clarify the situation. There are many ways to use this code incorrectly, which is why I need to see the entire code, manifest.json, and a description of the desired workflow.

Comment: @wOxxOm thank you for your help I handled it.  Again I have another problem now :| when I open the popup in every page, is it rendered ? In my case it rendered once